# How to pass a template function in a template argument list

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-templates

Suppose I have a `template` function:

```
template<typename T>
T produce_5_function() { return T(5); }
```

How can I pass this entire `template` to another `template`?

If `produce_5_function` was a functor, there would be no problem:

```
template<typename T>
struct produce_5_functor {
  T operator()() const { return T(5); }
};
template<template<typename T>class F>
struct client_template {
  int operator()() const { return F<int>()(); }
};
int five = client_template< produce_5_functor >()();
```

but I want to be able to do this with a raw function template:

```
template<??? F>
struct client_template {
  int operator()() const { return F<int>(); }
};
int five = client_template< produce_5_function >()();
```

I suspect the answer is "you cannot do this".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I suspect the answer is "you cannot do this".

Yes, that is the case, you cannot pass a function template as a template argument. From 14.3.3:

> A template-argument for a template template-parameter shall be the
>   name of a class template or an alias template, expressed as
>   id-expression.

The template function needs to be instantiated *before* you pass it to the other template. One possible solution is to pass a class type that holds a static `produce_5_function` like so:

```
template<typename T>
struct Workaround {
  static T produce_5_functor() { return T(5); }
};
template<template<typename>class F>
struct client_template {
  int operator()() const { return F<int>::produce_5_functor(); }
};
int five = client_template<Workaround>()();
```

Using alias templates, I could get a little closer:

```
template <typename T>
T produce_5_functor() { return T(5); }

template <typename R>
using prod_func = R();

template<template<typename>class F>
struct client_template {
  int operator()(F<int> f) const { return f(); }
};

int five = client_template<prod_func>()(produce_5_functor);
```

Comment: Is there a fundamental reason why template template parameters cannot be function templates? Is this likely to be addressed in the future?

Comment: @Olumide: Probably because it's a lot of additional complexity and easy to work around (see mfontanini's answer).  Same goes for partial specialization, which is used a whole lot more than template template arguments.

Answer (score 6):

How about wrapping that function?

```
template<typename T>
struct produce_5_function_wrapper {
    T operator()() const { return produce_5_function<T>(); }
};
```

Then you can use the wrapper instead of the function:

```
int five = client_template< produce_5_function_wrapper >()();
```

Using the template function alone will not work, there's no such thing as "template template functions".