# For each type, call a template function with each of these types

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

As the title says, I'm trying to create something to be used as followed :

```cpp
template <typename T>
void testFunc(int& i)
{
    ...
}
```

```cpp
int i { 0 };
ForEach<int, float>::run<testFunc>(i);
```

I've already tried some things, but I'm hitting some problems:

```cpp
template<typename CurrentComponentType, typename... ComponentTypes>
struct ForEach
{
    template<void (&func)(auto&&... args)>
    static constexpr void run(auto&&... args)
    {
        func<CurrentComponentType>(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        ForEach<ComponentTypes...>::run<func>(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    }
};

template<typename CurrentComponentType>
struct ForEach<CurrentComponentType>
{
    template<void (&func)(auto&&... args)>
    static constexpr void run(auto&&... args)
    {
        func<CurrentComponentType>(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    }
};
```

1. I don't know how to take a template function as a (template but not necessarily) argument.
2. For some reasons that I don't understand, I cannot call again the `run()` function as so: `run<func>(`. It says `'<unresolved overloaded function type>'`.

I think there are multiple things I don't understand.

How can I fix it, and why doesn't it work this way? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: `testFunc` isn't a function, it's a template function, but the template parameter for `run()` is a function rather than a template function.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that indeed explain the 2nd problem... but I dont have any idea how to resolve it...

Comment: In C++20 you can do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/s8hE7zaMP), are you okay with using lambdas instead of template functions?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I am, I just didn't know there is a difference

Comment: A lambda (even with template parameters) is a value, whereas a template function is a template value. C++ doesn't support non-type template template parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651488/how-to-pass-a-template-function-in-a-template-argument-list

Comment: Here's another approach in C++17 if you make `testFunc` a template class with an `operator()`: https://godbolt.org/z/fh58noMWs

Answer (score 0):

Each of the solutions below can be used like so:

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    int i { 0 };
    ForEach<int, float>::run<testFunc>(i);
}
```

Because [you can't pass an uninstantiated template function as a (template) parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15651770/1541563), you need to make it a template class with an `operator()`:

```cpp
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct testFunc
{
    void operator()(int& i) {}
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct ForEach
{
    template<template<typename> typename F, typename... Args>
    static constexpr void run(Args&&... args)
    {
        ForEach<T>::template run<F>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        ForEach<Ts...>::template run<F>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct ForEach<T>
{
    template<template<typename> typename F, typename... Args>
    static constexpr void run(Args&&... args)
    {
        F<T>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Starting in C++17, you can use [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to avoid recursion:

```cpp
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct testFunc
{
    void operator()(int& i) {}
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct ForEach
{
    template<template<typename> typename F, typename... Args>
    static constexpr void run(Args&&... args)
    {
        (F<Ts>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...), ...);
    }
};
```

Finally, in C++20 you also have the option to use a [lambda with a template parameter list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead:

```cpp
#include <utility>

auto testFunc = []<typename T>(int& i) {};

template<typename... Ts>
struct ForEach
{
    template<auto F, typename... Args>
    static constexpr void run(Args&&... args)
    {
        (F.template operator()<Ts>(std::forward<Args>(args)...), ...);
    }
};
```